# How to workaround bulk trigger in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, triggers, bulk

I have some Insert triggers in MsSQL using "select from inserted..." and process all the rows at once.

MySQL has mandatory keyword "FOR EACH ROW" and is not able to create such trigger.

I have tried the "for each row" option, however the performance results are slow.

Do you have any workarounds for such situation?

Example of insert trigger content:

```
select @batchContent = (           
SELECT i.[content]          
FROM inserted i           
)

EXEC SendMultipleRecords @batchContent = @batchContent
```

Multiple insert contents are set into array variable and send to stored procedure, that does it's own logic to populate them etc... and due to many records it is the performance critical point

Comment: The workaround is, unfortunately, to redesign the logic of your trigger to work with a single row. This can be trivial, this can be complicated, this can even be impossible with just a trigger (as not everything you can do in a batch trigger has an equivalent in a for-each-trigger; but since your problem is "just" being slow, it's probably not the case here). Without seeing your code, we can't answer your question though, there is no general way/workaround to translate this. So please add your original code, your mysql translated code, and an explanation of what your trigger is supposed to do.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for the answer, I have updated the question with a snapchot of code that might present the problem... It is still pretty general, but I think it shows the main problem.... The MySql translated code I don't have... just for the "for each row" option which works properly

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, this part will present a problem. The solution is the same as before: you can probably replace your procedure "SendMultipleRecords" with a procedure "SendOneRecord" that does whatever the other procedure does, just does it for a single record (assuming it makes sense to split the behaviour into processing single records, which we do not know without knowing what the code does). If you need help with that, add your original code, your mysql translated code, and an explanation of what your procedure is supposed to do.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  I see two things that seem to be syntax errors.

Comment: @RickJames  Version 8. But if you mean syntax errors in provided snapchot, it is MsSQL example of trigger that I need to convert to MySQL.

Comment: It won't be that simple.  MySQL does not have the concept of arrays.  You will need to understand what the SQL is doing, and rewrite it.

Comment: @RickJames seems so... most likely the batching logic will be handled somewhere in application layer... Stack overflow question was just one last shot in the dark if someone already solved something similar

Comment: Probably need to back up a step -- Rather than looking at a single query that is hard to translate to MySQL, let's look at the task that that query is a part of.  It may, for example, involve creating a temp table with the "array", then processing them.  And it probably will not involve a Trigger, but application code.

Comment: Well the problem is about populating records to other databases... therefore as you say... I will probably insert all the records to one table, then load them to some component that will inside do some batching logic in code and handles the inserts to other databases as a batch.
I think this question can be closed probably